# Azure Devops PR based pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, devops, pull-request

I have requirement where i need an azure pipeline stage to be triggered after completing the Pull Request. I have enabled branch policy which triggers my pipeline successfully. My pipeline consists of two stages as mentioned below (sample code)

```
stages:
  - stage: plan
    displayName: 'terraform plan'
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
    ...
  - stage: apply
    displayName: 'terraform apply'
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
    ...
```

Upon raising the Pull request both the stages are executing(in sequence), I need only plan stage to be executed first and pause the pipeline until the PR gets merged. Once the PR is merged the apply stage should resume. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work that way when using stages. The pipeline is triggered on the PR, but then there aren't any new triggers from that point forward. On merge a new pipeline can trigger.

While the on-PR-pipeline has not completed, it won't report status to the PR. It needs to complete to successfully close the PR.

You can re-use the build artifacts if you need them though.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a condition on the stage. It would be

```
    - ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')}} :
      - stage: apply
        displayName: 'terraform apply'
        condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
```

This would only execute the apply stage if it is part of a PR request completion and if it is off the main branch.

For clarification it is using the [Predefined ADO variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services).

Another option is to add an [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) and have  gate on the environment.

You really don't need the condition if condition but I put that on there to not even load the stage if it's not of the main branch.  The actual condition is the piece that won't execute the stage.